# How to Connect magento 1.9 to magento 1.5 DB

Tags: php, mysql, magento

How to Connect magento 1.9 to magento 1.5 DB or How to upgrade magento 1.5 to 1.9
How to Connect magento 1.9 to magento 1.5 DB or How to upgrade magento 1.5 to 1.9

Answer (score 1):

@Vikas, Please check below procedure for upgrade magento.

General Upgrade Procedure from Magento 1.5 to 1.9

```
1) Take a backup of current database and current 1.5 Magento code.

2) Then Download magento version 1.9 from here => http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

3) Backup your 1.5 magento source code & remove all folders and files from your 1.5 source code.

4) Place all folders and files from the 1.9.

5) Then from your old source-code (i.e magento 1.5) merge your following folders into the 1.9

    - Community app/code/community
    - Local app/code/local
    - Media 
    - Your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/<ur theme> or app/design/frontend/<your package>)
    - Custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
    - Copy your custom xml files from app/etc/modules/ to current app/etc/modules/
    - Any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.
    - Copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (1.5) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).
    Custom js files if any from app/js/.

6) Then Go to app/etc/local.xml. & edit database details & put your database username and password and database name.

7) Now You're done,check the site.
```

Let me know if you still have any confusion for the same !